# How to use Tag on dynamic button in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, tags, ios7

I have created buttons by using for loop. The buttons are made perfectly fine. Now I have to single IB action for all of the dynamic buttons. I have set tag too.The code I am using is below written. But the action is not identifying the exact button which I want to use.

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){

     btnphoto=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,(30*i)+110,50,20)];

     [btnphoto setTitle:@"Photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [btnphoto addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     btnphoto.tag=100 + i;

     [self.view addSubview:btnphoto];

}

-(void)someMethod:(UIButton *)sender{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

In someMethod method -

```
UIButton *button = sender;

int buttonTagIndex = button.tag;
```

Now buttonTagIndex gives you tag index for selected button.

Comment: Hello Smita.Thanks for the answer,.If i want to say change the colour of the button for example.and on every button i have to perform same .i.e for each button the same should be perform.then how can i achieve that .

Comment: I am not getting you properly. If you want to perform same thing on every button action then no need of getting button tag. but if you want to change button color then you can.

Comment: you are rite …Sorry i was wrong ..But if i have to change different color on each button action ..then how can i do that

Comment: @user2754190 please see my answer... it will help you as you want...if any query then please ask

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){

    UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,(30*i)+110,50,20)];

    [button setTitle:@"Photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.tag=100 + i;

    [self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

To show diffrent color, first add color in array

```
NSMutableArray *colorArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor greenColor],nil];
```

then

```
-(void)someMethod:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Btn Tag = %d",sender.tag);
    int randomNum=arc4random()%3;
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[colorArray objectAtIndex:randomNum]];
}
```

Comment: Hello Rajneesh,Thanks for your answer..I use this code..Now on each button it make the colour red.But if i want that first button have red colour and 2nd have blue and third have other then how can i do that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually access the tag property of the button from within the function to determine which button has called the selector.

```
-(void)someMethod:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIButton *tappedButton = sender;

    NSInteger tag = tappedButton.tag;
    NSLog(@"This is the button with tag: %ld",tag);

    [tappedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: yes from this code//now i have identify on which button i have click on..Bot say for an example if on every button click.i want to change the buttons colour.can you please tell that how can i do that .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the color or any property then you can do as follows

//i just giving you example of how can i change the title of the UIButton same way you can change color property... i have just used this in my some code..

```
 -(void)someMethod:(id)sender {
          //1...this will change all the button title with string "Changed" 
            [sender setTitle:@"Changed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


         //2..now if you want to just change the property of uibutton on basis of tag value
             [(UIButton *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:Your_TAG_VALUE] setTitle:@"JustChanged" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender{     

       UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
       int *btn_tag=btn.tag;

       NSLog(@"This is the button with tag: %d", btn_tag);


    }
```

Comment: Hello OmPrakash.i want to say change the colour of the button for example.and on every button i have to perform same .i.e for each button the same should be perform.then how can i achieve that .

Comment: UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:btn_tag];
  [btn setBackgroundColor:color];

Answer (score 0):

As you have already set the tag for each button so just do the below to identify which button has been touched

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *TouchedButton=(UIButton *)sender;
    int TouchedButtonTag=[TouchedButton tag]; // Now you can uniquely identify your buttons by this tag. 
    // do your stuff for respective button touched event

   switch([TouchedButton tag])
   {
      case :101
           [TouchedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
           break;

      case :102
           [TouchedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
           break;

      case :103
           [TouchedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
           break;

     // and so on...
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello tapas.If i want to say change the colour of the button for example.and on every button i have to perform same .i.e for each button the same should be perform.then how can i achieve that .

Answer (score 0):

Try the above code, this might be helpful :

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender{
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:btn_tag];
    switch([btn tag])
    {
     case :101
       [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        break;

      case :102
           [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
           break;

      case :103
           [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
           break;
   }
}
```